# What version of ubuntu should I install given my need for a secure web client?

Tags: installation, distro-recommendation

I am totally new to ubuntu, and wish to install it on a virtual server.  My reasons and implementation desires are listed below.  Would ubuntu server or desktop be most suitable for me?  Would the 32 or 64 bit version be more suitable for me? Thank you

- Purpose:  A secure computer for Internet access to banking, etc which
  will only be used for this purpose, and maybe TurboTax if it runs on
  ubuntu.
- Host: Centos 6 server without GUI running on x86_64 box located in my garage with existing WiFi to my home network.
- Intended VM software: VirtualBox using phpVirtualBox.
- How I will access it: Probably remote desktop via Windows 7 PCs, and restrict to clients located on my LAN.

  ```
  [root@desktop Logs]# cat /proc/cpuinfo
  processor       : 0
  vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
  cpu family      : 6
  model           : 58
  model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3330 CPU @ 3.00GHz
  stepping        : 9
  cpu MHz         : 1600.000
  cache size      : 6144 KB
  physical id     : 0
  siblings        : 4
  core id         : 0
  cpu cores       : 4
  apicid          : 0
  initial apicid  : 0
  fpu             : yes
  fpu_exception   : yes
  cpuid level     : 13
  wp              : yes
  flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms
  bogomips        : 5986.54
  clflush size    : 64
  cache_alignment : 64
  address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  power management:

  processor       : 1
  vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
  cpu family      : 6
  model           : 58
  model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3330 CPU @ 3.00GHz
  stepping        : 9
  cpu MHz         : 1600.000
  cache size      : 6144 KB
  physical id     : 0
  siblings        : 4
  core id         : 1
  cpu cores       : 4
  apicid          : 2
  initial apicid  : 2
  fpu             : yes
  fpu_exception   : yes
  cpuid level     : 13
  wp              : yes
  flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms
  bogomips        : 5986.54
  clflush size    : 64
  cache_alignment : 64
  address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  power management:

  processor       : 2
  vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
  cpu family      : 6
  model           : 58
  model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3330 CPU @ 3.00GHz
  stepping        : 9
  cpu MHz         : 3001.000
  cache size      : 6144 KB
  physical id     : 0
  siblings        : 4
  core id         : 2
  cpu cores       : 4
  apicid          : 4
  initial apicid  : 4
  fpu             : yes
  fpu_exception   : yes
  cpuid level     : 13
  wp              : yes
  flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms
  bogomips        : 5986.54
  clflush size    : 64
  cache_alignment : 64
  address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  power management:

  processor       : 3
  vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
  cpu family      : 6
  model           : 58
  model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3330 CPU @ 3.00GHz
  stepping        : 9
  cpu MHz         : 3001.000
  cache size      : 6144 KB
  physical id     : 0
  siblings        : 4
  core id         : 3
  cpu cores       : 4
  apicid          : 6
  initial apicid  : 6
  fpu             : yes
  fpu_exception   : yes
  cpuid level     : 13
  wp              : yes
  flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms
  bogomips        : 5986.54
  clflush size    : 64
  cache_alignment : 64
  address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  power management:

  [root@desktop Logs]#
  ```

Comment: take the 64-bit if the CPU has the capability, is it a server? install ubuntu server. Is it a desktop/laptop then install desktop edition. you can install a GUI on the server edition if you want to...

Comment: @Alvar.  CPU info is listed on my original post.  I had previously tried to install Windows7 on the virtual server, but it complained about it not being 64 bit.  Hopefully, I will not still have that problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than giving you an outright answer of *what* to use, I'm going to suggest what to look for, and *why* to select a specific varient.

You'll likely need a gui, so you're best off going with one of the officially supported GUI variations, rather than server, or minimal. If you're a newbie, xubuntu and lubuntu might be good fits since they're both lightweight and are pretty simple to install. I generally wouldn't recommend the big two derivatives - ubuntu and kubuntu since both of them have composited desktops and other shiny things you don't need

With your specific use-case there's no compelling reason to go 64 bit, or to give your VM heaps of ram - most browsers are frustratingly 32 bit only

Turbotax's desktop version [may not work very well on linux under wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=623), though confusingly [there's reports the online version works fine](http://www.democraticunderground.com/1097199) if you run the windows firefox version under wine.

Answer (score 1):

Unless TurboTax has a command line interface I'm not aware of, I believe you are going to need the desktop version, but that is not going to work if you're running VirtualBox on a server distro.   As for the architecture, 32 bit matches your host but either will work because this is a virtual machine.  If security is a big issue, choose your wireless router's password well, disable remote logins to the Host machine and restrict clients to the VM like you suggested.